# Find the top 2 accounts with the maximum number of unique patients on a monthly basis

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Find the top 2 accounts with the maximum number of unique patients on a monthly
basis.
Patient logs table

```
Account Id | date | Patient Id
1 2-1-2020 100
1 27-1-2020 200
2 1-1-2020 300
2 21-1-2020 400
2 21-1-2020 300
2 1-1-2020 500
3 20-1-2020 400
1 4-3-2020 500
```

sample output

```
Month |Account ID | no of unique patients
January 2 3
January 1 2
March 3 1
```

*Note: Prefer the Account Id with the least value in case of same number of unique patients

Comment: whats your database?

Comment: i am using Mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select aym.*
from (select accountId, year(date) as yyyy, month(date) as mm,
             count(distinct patient_id) as num_patients,
             row_number() over (partition by year(date), month(date) order by count(distinct patient_id) as seqnum
      from t
      group by accountId, year(date), month(date)
     ) aym
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Date functions vary widely among databases.  `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` are common functions; if your database doesn't support them, you should be able to find the right functions.

Comment: i am still not able to get my output, it gives me an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by year(date), month(date) order by count(distinct patient_id) as seq' at line 4

Comment: @RidaShahwar . . . This requires MySQL 8+, which was released three years ago.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by month,AccountID order by count(distinct patienId) desc) rn
)  t
where t.rn < 3
```

Comment: The question does not specify which RDBMS should be used.. This answer is only an option for MSSQL I guess.

Comment: @hastrb window functions are available almost in every database

Comment: The key is `almost`.